# How to create an IIS Web Deploy Package from dotnet cli running in Linux

Tags: asp.net-core, web-deployment, dotnet-cli

I have an ASP.NET Core app which currently runs under IIS in a Windows Server machine. To deploy that app there's a release pipeline that takes a Web Deployment Package (zip) as input.

I'm trying to create that Web Deployment Package from a Linux VM with a command similar to this:

```
dotnet build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="/temp/WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site" /p:VirtualDirectory="" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

This is causing this error:

```
usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.400/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeployPackage.targets(183,5): error MSB4181: The "CreateManifestFile" task returned false but did not log an error. [/app/WebApp.csproj]
```

Anyone knows how to fix this problem? I googled and search other SO answers but couldn't find anybody trying to build a Web Deployment Package from a Linux OS.

I can successfully build that same project from a Windows VM that has Visual Studio installed but can't do it from Linux. I understand some features are tightly related to Visual Studio but I'm surprised there's no work around or any documentation at all on how to get this done.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not a surprise, that Linux know nothing about IIS. And as I remember that old fashioned .zip deployment packages worked with IIS only. May be it's time to use new [deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=netcore-cli) methods and change deployment pipeline accordingly. ASP.NET Core doesn't have backward compatibility with old ASP.NET and never meant to.

Comment: I was trying to do it without breaking backward compatibility with my release pipeline. I understand that Web Deployment Packages is really old technology. But if I can build it from the CLI in a Windows machine I don't really see why not I can't do the same in Linux. Seems like something isn't supported but I doubt it's a hardcore dependency to Windows. It must be just a missing csproj feature/task of some sort. If ultimately I have to redo the entire build/release pipeline so be it but I was hoping to avoid that.